# Some way to force delegate work for Iframe content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  var $result_link = $('#sample_test').contents().find('#get_result_link');
```

This is how I find link in iframe with id `#sample_test`

This code works:

```
$result_link.click(function(){
       if ($contents.find('.new_answer').length!=0){
               $('html, body').animate({
                   scrollTop: $contents.find('.new_answer').first().offset().top/2
               }, 500);
           }
});
```

But there are AJAX actions on iframe source, which can unbind this 'click' (reload element with this link). And usual `delegate` doesn't work ( I use appropriate version of JQ)

```
  $('body').delegate('#sample_test', 'click', function(){
       if ($contents.find('.new_answer').length!=0){
           $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: $contents.find('.new_answer').first().offset().top/2
           }, 500);
       }


    })
```

Comment: What jQuery version do you use? Use `on` instead of delegate..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event propagation does not cross frame boundaries.

You need to bind the delegating handler to the `<iframe>`'s `<body>`.

Comment: $('#sample_test').contents().find('body').on(...) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
var frame = $('iframe').contents();

frame.on('click', '#sample_test', function() {
   // Code here.
});
```

This way you are applying the event to the frame and not the parent.